# How do you select into a nested type in oracle pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to be able to delete by rowid then immediately insert the data being deleted in an audit table.

There are far too many records to 
`INSERT INTO ... SELECT CRITERIA` then `DELETE ... CRITERIA`.

I already know how to do everything just using rowid and `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Inside package body:

```
TYPE some_type IS RECORD (
   row_id    ROWID,
   full_row  table_name%ROWTYPE
);
TYPE some_type_list IS TABLE OF some_type
   INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE do_stuff
IS
   lc_data  SYS_REFCURSOR;
   lt_recs  some_type_list;
BEGIN
   OPEN lc_date FOR
      SELECT rowid, a.*
      FROM   table_name;
   LOOP
      FETCH lc_data
      BULK COLLECT INTO lt_recs
      LIMIT 50000;
      EXIT WHEN lt_recs.COUNT = 0;
      --
      FORALL i IN lt_recs.FIRST..lt_recs.LAST
         DELETE table_name
         WHERE  ROWID = lt_recs(i).row_id;
      --
      FORALL i IN lt_recs.FIRST..lt_recs.LAST
         INSERT INTO table_name_audit VALUES lt_recs(i).full_row;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

If I try that i get the following error:

`Line: 117 Column: 25 Type: error Text: PLS-00597: expression 'LT_RECS' in the INTO list is of wrong type`

Comment: You might want to consider doing this in a BEFORE DELETE trigger instead of in program logic.

Comment: It isn't going to be done for every delete. Only this package. Also, triggers tend to be a bit evil. Best to avoid whenever possible.

Comment: Try declaring `lc_data IS CURSOR FOR SELECT ROWID, a.* FROM table_name a` outside of your procedure, then declare your type as `TYPE some_type_list IS TABLE OF LC_DATA%ROWTYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER`.  Might be worth a try.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "There are far too many records to INSERT INTO ... SELECT CRITERIA then DELETE ... CRITERIA." ? Why should the number of records prevent you from doing it in plain SQL?

Comment: what is the structure of your table?

Comment: Digging through some of my old posts reminded me of a potential solution for this question as well. Take a look [at this question and my answer to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213489/ora-00947-not-enough-values-while-declaring-type-globally/10213666#10213666).  You might have to change your RECORD declaration to be an OBJECT, but have a look.  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle versions prior to 11gR2 restrict us to use BULK COLLECT into a collection (nested table or varray) of records. Read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a77069/04_colls.htm) on Oracle Docs.

If you want to see how it is done in 11gR2, scroll down to **EDIT 2** section of this answer.

An alternative tho this can be the use of separate collections for every column- an approach that is most widely used. In this you can have:

```
/*
TYPE some_type IS RECORD (
   row_id    ROWID,
   full_row  table_name%ROWTYPE
);
TYPE some_type_list IS TABLE OF some_type
   INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
-- */
CREATE TYPE t_row_id IS TABLE OF ROWID;
CREATE TYPE t_col1 IS TABLE OF table_name.col1%TYPE;
CREATE TYPE t_col2 IS TABLE OF table_name.col2%TYPE;
CREATE TYPE t_col3 IS TABLE OF table_name.col3%TYPE;
...
...
CREATE TYPE t_colN IS TABLE OF table_name.colN%TYPE;

PROCEDURE do_stuff
IS
   lc_data  SYS_REFCURSOR;
   -- lt_recs  some_type_list;
   row_id t_row_id;
   col1 t_col1;
   col2 t_col2;
   col3 t_col3;
   ...
   ...
   colN t_colN;
BEGIN
   OPEN lc_date FOR
      SELECT rowid, a.*
      FROM   table_name;
   LOOP
      FETCH lc_data
      BULK COLLECT INTO row_id, col1, col2, col3, ..., colN
      LIMIT 50000;
      EXIT WHEN lt_recs.COUNT = 0;
      --
      FORALL i IN row_id.FIRST..row_id.LAST
         DELETE table_name
         WHERE  ROWID = row_id(i);
      --
      FORALL i IN col1.FIRST..col1.LAST
         INSERT INTO table_name_audit VALUES (col1(i), col2(i), col3(i), ..., colN(i));
   END LOOP;
END;
```

I have not removed many of the rows in your program in order to let you understand the changes.

**EDIT :** Refer to the "Restrictions on BULK COLLECT" section of the Oracle Docs link I have given above and also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/appdev.817/a77069/04_colls.htm).

---

**EDIT #2 :**

---

You have to use `CREATE TYPE ... IS OBJECT` instead of `RECORD`. Also, You need to modify the `SELECT` statement the way I have done when I tried it. Please see the Oracle Docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96624/05_colls.htm) and a StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213489/ora-00947-not-enough-values-while-declaring-type-globally) for further reference.

The code I tried on my machine (runs Oracle 11g R2) is as follows:

-- SELECT * FROM user_objects WHERE object_type = 'TYPE';
    CLEAR SCREEN;
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE temp_t_test AS OBJECT ( -- << OBJECT, not RECORD.
  test_id  INTEGER
, test_val VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE temp_tbl_test AS TABLE OF TEMP_T_TEST;
/

DECLARE
  v_test TEMP_TBL_TEST;
BEGIN
  SELECT temp_t_test(t_id, t_val) -- << Notice the syntax
  -- I'm selecting the columns as the defined OBJECT type.
  BULK COLLECT INTO v_test
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS t_id, 'ABCD' AS t_val FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 'WXYZ' FROM dual
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 3, 'PQRS' FROM dual);

  dbms_output.put_line('Bulk Collect Successful!');
END;
/
```

** OUTPUT **:

```
TYPE temp_t_test compiled
TYPE temp_tbl_test compiled
anonymous block completed
Bulk Collect Successful!
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at the documentation.

Comment: @scrappythenell: I have edited the answer. Please check. I hope it is useful to you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that I'd take this approach at all, to be honest.

A faster method would be along the lines of performing a multitable insert:

1. insert the table columns into the audit table, possibly using direct path (APPEND hint) for efficiency
2. insert the rowid's into an on-commit-delete-rows global temporary table.

Then perform a delete against the original table using DELETE .. WHERE ROWID IN (SELECT ORIGINAL_ROWID FROM MY_GLOBAL_TEMP_TAB)

... and then commit.

Faster, and less code I think.

Comment: I like the idea of temp tables in general, but they don't perform well enough on large data sets. I'm already doing an `insert into select by rowid` then `delete by rowid`, so I'm not really looking for the alternatives. I've seen what i'm looking for done before, but don't remember the exact syntax.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if performance doesn't beat a PL/SQL-based method -- I've never seen a problem with large GTT myself. Your choice though.

Comment: We are working on billions of records. It's not exactly common volume.

Comment: The higher the volume, the more inclined I'd be to use a GTT rather than a pl/sql method. Of course, you'd do better with truncating or dropping partitions, but SQL is always going to beat PL/SQL.

Comment: In practice that is not always true. Especially when you consider multi-threading. also you can't truncate if you are only deleting certain records.

Comment: Multi-threading can apply to SQL just as well as it can to PL/SQL, with or without parallel query. It's pretty rare that there's a need to go to those lengths though. Yes, there are of course limitation on truncation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139630/whats-the-difference-between-truncate-and-delete-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to works in 11gR2 - what version are you on?.

The only wrong-looking thing in your post is this:

```
OPEN lc_date FOR
  SELECT rowid, a.*
  FROM   table_name;
```

It ought to be this ...

```
OPEN lc_data FOR
  SELECT a.rowid, a.*
  FROM   table_name a;
```

... but these may simply be typos you introduced when sanitizing your code to post here.